# Reading file, adding words and numbers in line of text into dictionary?

Tags: python, text, dictionary, key

I'm trying to write a Python code that will allow me to take in text, and read it line
by line. In each line, the words just go into the dictionary as a key and the numbers should be the assigned values, as a list.
For example, the file will be composed of hundreds of lines that have the same format as this:

> Peter 17 29 24 284 72

Ideally, the name "Peter" would be a key in the dictionary, and the values would be `dict[Peter]: [17, 19, 24, 284,7273]`.

My problem so far is adding numbers. I'm not sure how to assign them to key values.

```
    def wordDict(filename):
        inFile=open(filename, 'r')
        line=inFile.readline()
        while line: 
            txtWords = line.split() # splits at white space
            wordScores={} # make dict
            scoreList=[]
            for word in txtWords:
                word.lower() # turns word into lowercase
                if word in string.ascii_lowercase:   #if word is alphabetical 
                    if word not in wordScores.keys():
                        wordScores=wordScores[word] # add the key to dictionary
```

---------- All I have

Comment: It appears that you haven't posted your full code, otherwise you have a syntax error. The else clause must have something in in, or be removed.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo left over from some incorrect code.

Answer (score 1):

Using Python 3.2:

```
with open("d://test.txt", "r") as fi:  # Data read from a text file is a string
    d = {}
    for i in fi.readlines():
        # So you split the line into a list
        temp = i.split()
        # So, temp = ['Peter', '17', '29', '24', '284', '72']

        # You could split 'temp' like so:
        #    temp[0] would resolve to 'Peter'
        #    temp[1] would resolve to ['17', '29', '24', '284', '72']
        name, num = temp[0], temp[1:]

        # From there, you could make temp[0] the key and temp[1:] the value.
        # But: notice that the numbers are still represented as strings.
        # So, we use the built-in function map() to turn them into integers.
        d[name] = [map(int, num)]
```

Comment: `[map(int, num)]` will make a list of a list of ints, which is almost certainly not what is desired. (a list of a list of ints looks like `[[7,8,9]]`)

Comment: I'm not sure if is desired behavior or not, but the OP's code only adds the list to the dict if the key is not already in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

If your lines all start with one word and then space delimited integers, you could do (untested):

```
myDict = {}
with open('inFile.txt','r') as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        line = line.split()
        name = line[0].lower()
        if name not in myDict:
            myDict[name] = map(int,line[1:])
```

Comment: `map()` is simple, it takes a function and a list and returns a list of the results of calling the function on each item in the list. In this case it converts the strings that you read from the file into ints. It is equivalent to the list comprehension `[int(x) for x in line[1:]]`

Answer (score 0):

I'll highlight two main issues with your code:

1. `for word in string.ascii_lowercase:` is the same as writing `for 'hello' in ['a','b,'c']:`, it won't do what you are expecting; and the loop will never run.
2. `wordScores = wordScores[word]` this is not adding anything to the key, you probably meant `wordScores[word] = []`.

Try this instead:

```
from collections import defauldict
words = defaultdict(list)

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      if line.strip():
         bits = line.split()
         if bits[0].isalpha():
             words[bits[0].lower()] += bits[1:]
```